# What are rules for when consecutive spaces will appear in html?

Tags: html, whitespace

I thought that `&nbsp` was necessary any time you wanted more than one space character to show up in html, but [this site](http://passionfool.com/Passionfool_2011/Production_History.html) is showing me that multiple consecutive spaces are all being rendered... why is that?

Comment: where on that site do you see that?

Comment: @DA the 'table' at the bottom is just lined up with spaces

Comment: The spaces occur between the dates of the plays and the titles.  If you `inspect elements` you will see that there are just spaces in there, no `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look closely at the source (before it is interpreted by a browser), you'll find that the website does in fact use `&nbsp;` very heavily in the site:

Example (before the **ONE FOR THE ROAD** line)

```
<span style="line-height: 23px;"class="style_3">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span>

<span style="line-height: 23px; " class="style_1">
    ONE FOR THE ROAD
</span>
```

Try saving the page to your computer (with the browser's saving functionality, not copy-paste), and view the source in Notepad or a similar text editor, and you will see the `&nbsp;` entity everywhere.

Comment: oh!  In chrome in both the inspector and the 'view source' it doesn't show the &nbsp; s.. I assumed it would, and I guess that's why I was confused.  I guess the question becomes where do you have to go to actually see the non-breaking spaces?

Comment: Check out my post, I've updated it. Try saving the page and viewing it in notepad. As a general rule, if you see many spaces that aren't collapsing into one, the `&nbsp;` entity is being used.

Comment: odd.. I opened it in notepad and in notepad++ and I do not see any &nbsp; characters

Comment: Try this: right-click on the page, Click Save As..., click save. Navigate to Production History.htm and open with Notepad++. Do a text search for `&nbsp;`. I can find hundreds of the things.

Comment: that did it! The other time I saved it from the view source, which I guess had already processed them out. So I guess I am right about how &nbsp; is supposed to work, but now I know not to expect to see them in any kind of 'view source' situation

Comment: @Damon - &nbsp; is just a entity reference for a character. When hand coding a page it's a convenient way of entering the non-breaking space character. But it is not the actual character. What the passionfool page is doing is sending the actual character, encoded as UTF-8, which when displayed in view source just looks like a normal space. When you do save as... the save process converts them to &nbsp; entity references so that they are convenient for use in a text editor. If a page sends the entity reference &nbsp;, that's what you'll see in 'view source'

Answer (score 1):

A regular space () wraps to the next line.
A non-breaking space `&nbsp;` prevents wrapping to the next line.

Assume the |   | are sides of the div:

This is how a regular space will be rendered:

```
| |    
| |
| |
| |
```

A non-breaking space however will continue on the same line. In HTML, this will cause the element that the space is in to stretch beyond it's `auto` width.

```
|  |    
| |
| |
| |
```

This will in turn push out the entire width of that side:

```
|  |    
|  |
|  |
|  |
```

Multiple whitespace characters will render, however they do not perform the same way a non-breaking whitespace does.

**Take a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/boomer101/vnTsC/), it will clear any confusion up.**

Answer (score 1):

A much cleaner way is to use CSS `white-space` property.

Having the value set to `pre` or `pre-wrap` or `pre-line` will all display multiple spaces (line break handling will be different with each).

Here's a good post about that: http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-white-space/

Comment: that makes sense and "In (X)HTML, anytime you string together a bunch of spaces in your code, the actual page output in your browser will, by default, trim (or collapse) all those spaces down to a single space." is how I'd always thought things worked.. but in that page there are a bunch of spaces together that are not collapsed, and I don't see a whitespace css property.. there is some javascript going on, though

Comment: What I have seen is posts that talk about CSS and stuff, often post the output as images rather than actual code. That seems to be the case here too. I have seen this property work as I'm using it currently in my project. But why take my word, fiddle on your own! :)

Answer (score 0):

@Damon

`&nbsp;` is the entity used to represent a non-breaking space. It is essentially a space, the primary difference being that a browser should not break (or wrap) a line of text at the point that this entity occupies, it also prevents the collapsing of multiple consecutive whitespace characters into a single space, which is the current browsers standard behaviour.

When you look into the source of the site that you [mention](http://passionfool.com/Passionfool_2011/Production_History.html), you can see that the site in fact is using the `&nbsp;` entity to format the text:

```
<span class="style_3" style="line-height: 23px; ">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>
```